# Set query parameter based on current URL

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working on a standard paging component for my project. All controllers with paging are waiting for PageIndex parameter in URL.

So I want to generate URL based on the current URL except for the PageIndex parameter.

For example, I have filters for my internet store like Manufacturer and MaxPrice.
A user opens the `mystore.com/products?manufacturer=Apple&MaxPrice=999` link.

Then he wants to go to the 3 pages. So the 3-page link in my paging should have the `mystore.com/products?manufacturer=Apple&MaxPrice=999&PageIndex=3` link.

[image]

So needed MVC function should:

1. Persists all existing params like MaxPrice and manufacturer
2. Replace only PageIndex param
3. **don't** use any hardcoded controller and action values (like controller = 'Products', Action = 'Index')

I try to use this code:

```
<a class="page-link" href="@Url.RouteUrl(new { PageIndex = page })">
    @page
</a>
```

It works fine except the 2 rule - it doesn't persist other arguments.
So if user click on this link he goes to `mystore.com/products?PageIndex=3`

Comment: you want to generate url bassed on current url, can you tell me why ?

Comment: Add a picture of what I want. Hope it helps. Yes, you right - I want to generate a new URL based on the current URL to persist other filter parameters (like Manufacturer and MaxPrice). In other words, I don't want to reset MaxPrice filter from URL after clicking on the 3 page of my paging (see picture). So the 3 page link should have the MaxPrice and Manufacturer params from original URL

Comment: perfect, I suggest to build the url dynamically by getting currentUrl with query strings "Request.Url.AbsoluteUri" then remove the pageIndex from url if exists , then add page index again, if you cannot understand let me know I can help.
hint : url must be defined as variable in your razor to make the things easier.

Comment: I know how to do it manually (like you described), but it looks like a rough and ugly solution. I have thought that there is some standard solution in Asp.net Core MVC for such problem (

Comment: You can make the things easy by creating extension method for to avoid adding complex code to your razor, I don't think that there is built in method to do your requirements

Comment: Get you! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to build the url dynamically by getting currentUrl with query strings "Request.Url.AbsoluteUri" then remove the pageIndex from url if exists , then add page index again.

hint : url must be defined as variable in your razor to make the things easier

To remove query string you can use regex

```
string queryString = "Default.aspx?Agent=10&Language=2"; //Request.QueryString.ToString();
string parameterToRemove="Language";   //parameter which we want to remove
string regex=string.Format("(&{0}=[^&\s]+|{0}=[^&\s]+&?)",parameterToRemove);
string finalQS = Regex.Replace(queryString, regex, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these to get the current url

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
// http://localhost:1302/TEST/Default.aspx

string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
// /TEST/Default.aspx
```

And then you can add the page index like this and redirect to that url

```
url = url+"&PageIndex=3";
```

**Recommended**

Or you can get the url parameters with

```
@Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["manufacturer"]
@Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["MaxPrice"]
```

And use those values to build the new URL inside the View